# UIButton wont call @IBAction

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

i'm new to swift and trying to call a loginAuth method when a UIButton is tapped. I'm doing exactly the same as i would have done in a objective-c project, but i keep getting following error:

```
[SwiftSwipeView.LoginViewController loginAuth]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

## UIButton

```
var logIn: UIButton!
```

## viewDidLoad

```
    logIn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (self.view.bounds.width/2)-(245/2), y: self.view.bounds.height-200, width: 245.00, height: 37.50));
    logIn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.29, green:0.345, blue:0.4, alpha:1)
    logIn.setTitle("LOG IN", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    logIn.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 14)
    logIn.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    logIn.clipsToBounds = true;
    logIn.addTarget(self, action: "loginAuth", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(logIn)
```

## LoginAuth Method

```
@IBAction func loginAuth(sender: UIButton!) {


    println("test")

}
```

Comment: Seems you are mixing objective-c and swift in one project. The error message looks like ObjC, your ode is Swift. Swift error messages look different.

Comment: Well the error appears as soon as i click the loginAuth button, so i guess the error should be between the loginAuth method and logIn button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
logIn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (self.view.bounds.width/2)-(245/2), y: self.view.bounds.height-200, width: 245.00, height: 37.50));
logIn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.29, green:0.345, blue:0.4, alpha:1)
logIn.setTitle("LOG IN", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

logIn.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 14)
logIn.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
logIn.clipsToBounds = true;
logIn.addTarget(self, action: "loginAuth:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(logIn)
```

As your loginAuth expecting a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare target action as you implemented.

Change this:

```
logIn.addTarget(self, action: "loginAuth", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

To

```
logIn.addTarget(self, action: "loginAuth:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

This message `unrecognized selector sent to instance` always indicate that method is not implemented which to try to execute...

Answer (score 0):

try this
 (add colon after selector name)

`logIn.addTarget(self, action: "loginAuth:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`